# Pip on RPi raises importerror: 'viewkeys' on any action

Tags: python, pip, importerror

I am running basically stock Raspian Jesse with both python 2.7 and 3.4 and am trying to install pillow, but whenever I do anything with the pip for 3.4, it issues

```
from six import with_metaclass, viewkeys, PY3
ImportError: cannot import name 'viewkeys'
```

I have attempted to simply reinstall six using pip, but that also triggers the error. According to the file, the six version is 1.8.0, which appears to be rather out-of-date, but I'm hesitant to simply replace the file. Can I simply replace the file's text, or do I need to edit other options?

Comment: You probably want to downgrade pip. Python 3.4 is not very recent, and thus the out-of-date six module will likely correspond to that Python version, while your pip version won't.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I hadn't thought of that...